# Drag and drop with Sikuli

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, sikuli

I am having trouble using drag and drop with Sikuli. I would like to drag something in any other direction (up, down, left, right) for a fixed number of pixels.

This looks like it should work:

```
t = find("1325249963143.png")
dragDrop(t, [t.x + 100, t.y + 100])
```

Sikuli IDE log says

```
[log] DRAG (741,525) to null
```

but the element is not dragged.

This works just fine:

```
dragDrop("1325249963143.png", "1325251471990.png")
```

The log says

```
[log] DRAG (741,525) to (507,490)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Environment: Mac OS X 10.7.2, Sikuli X-1.0rc3 (r905)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

only to say hello here - an alternative coding:

```
dragDrop(t, t.offset(Location(100, 100)))
```

Answer (score 9):

To [quote RaiMan (raimund-hocke)](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/172804):

> the first parameter is a Match object, which is ok. the second
>   prameter must be of type PSMRL too (see docs: Pattern/Image, String,
>   Match, Region or Location)

```
dragDrop(t, Location(t.x + 100, t.y + 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to drag an image down to a given location:

```
image1 = ("image1.png")
imageLoc = find(image1)
dragDrop(imageLoc, Location(imageLoc.getX() + 100, imageLoc.getY() + 100))
```