# Drag & drop from desktop with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, webdriver, drag, protractor

Is it possible to drag & drop a file from desktop to a web browser with protractorJS?

Answer (score 2):

It is not really about `Protractor` - it is about browser automation through `WebDriver` in general.

You can drag&drop from element to element, but not from or to something outside of the browser.

---

As an option, you can give this part of your automation to [`Sikuli`](http://www.sikuli.org/) automation tool, which doesn't care if there is a desktop, or browser under test - it is screenshot/image based, see more:

- [Drag and drop with Sikuli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679929/drag-and-drop-with-sikuli)